# antd with typescript : Table with Column align='right' is not compiling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using antd Table with Typescript as below

```
<Table dataSource={data} columns={columns2} />
```

When I give `align: 'right'` to one of the columns, it is not compiling.
The following error is shown. I couldn't figure out the root cause of these issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"right" | "left" | "center" | undefined'.  TS2322

    47 |   public render() {
    48 |     return (
  > 49 |       <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns2} />
       |                                ^
    50 |     );
    51 |   }
    52 | }
```

Full code is

```js
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";


const columns2 = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
    align: 'right'
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
];


export class Sales extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns2} />
    );
  }
}

export default Sales;
```

Comment: Would `align: 'right' as 'right'` fix it? https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/17281

Comment: https://ant.design/components/table/#Using-in-TypeScript check this out, there is a different approach compared to the plain JavaScript one

Comment: Thanks @Dario, @ carrany - Both the answers are working.

Answer (score 6):

```
import { AlignType } from 'rc-table/lib/interface';

align: 'right' as 'right',// not recommend
align: 'right' as const,// ok
align: 'right' as AlignType,// good
```

3 ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me.

```
align: 'right' as const,
```

So the code looks like this:

```
{
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
      align: 'right' as const,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one. its work for me

```
{
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
      align: 'right' as 'right',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its work for me

```
import { AlignType } from 'rc-table/lib/interface'
```

```
{
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
      align: 'right' as AlignType,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use align inside const.

this is an example column name

`{ title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name', align: "center", },`